# How to color the inner part of a 2D circle in THREEjs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The code bellow produces a circunference with a blue line in a dark screen:

```
let camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );

var radius = 1;
var vertices = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= 360; i++){
    vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(i*(Math.PI/180))*radius, Math.cos(i*(Math.PI/180))*radius, 0));
}

let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);

let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:"blue"})
var lineStrip = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add( lineStrip ); 

scene.add(camera);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I know that the object itself is just a line, but I'd like to fill the inner part of the line with a color. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "inner part", do you mean you want to render the circle as a disk? Then you need to render it as a mesh instead of lines. You can create this yourself from the same vertices by creating an index buffer, or more conveniently, make use of the [CircleGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleGeometry) class.